# How do I use an intermediary to connect tables in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have recently started working with Laravel and am looking to really start digging into it and all of its power. I am currently trying to do something fairly simple, pair a player with their corresponding stats. I have 3 classes and corresponding tables in my database:

```
Player 
Stats 
PlayerStatsLink
```

The PlayerStatsLink table has a 'player_id' and a 'stats_id' column that connects each player to their corresponding stats. Where I am getting somewhat confused is how to use the belongsTo and hasOne methods in this situation with the link. Right now here is what my classes look like:

Player.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model
{
    public function stats() 
    {

        return $this->hasOne('App\Stats');

    }
}
```

Stats.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stats extends Model
{
    public function players() 
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Player');

    }
}
```

I am confused as to how to incorporate my link class into the mix, even though I'm pretty sure it is the right thing to do based on what I have learned about databases and structures. I have considered adding a player_id column to the Stats table to make what I have right now work, but I'm not sure if that is the right way to do this.

What I would ideally like to be able to do to access this data after the PlayerStatsLink has connected a player with corresponding stats is something like this:

```
{{ $player->stats->points }}
```

Comment: Why do you need a `PlayerStatsLink` table in the first place? If your want to link 1 player to 1 stats, you only need 2 tables `player` and `stats`. Add `stats_id` in `player` table and use your relationship definition. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: Can you update your question to show schemas for the 3 tables?  It sounds like this is a `belongsToMany`.

Comment: I thought because I am going extend the functionality to include Gamelogs, which will feed the Stats table, it would make everything easier, but I see that it is still uneccesary and overcomplicating things to add a PlayerStatsLink in this case because it is a one to one relationship.

Comment: Hi, I think you have misunderstood the docs. If you have a table that uses `player_id` and `stats_id` then you are seeking a `Many-to-Many` relation between stats model and player model. But currently you have defined a `One-To-One` relation between them. I think you need to rethink structure. ask yourself if a player has many stats or not? Ask if a single belongs to many players or not. answer these questions and we can help much more.

Comment: @PeymanSeraj My plan was originally to have a stats column for each player for each game, but I instead decided that a Gamelog idea to track stats for individual games would make more sense. I see my mistake that I don't need the link anymore, now I am just wondering how to access the Stats corresponding to each player. I am trying to use `$id = $player->id;` `$stats = App\Player::find($id)->stats;` within my foreach loop which is getting all players to access the Stats like so `{{ $stats->goals }}` but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Okay. So tell me if I understand you well. ideally you want to have 3 models : Game, Player and Stats. So each Game can have many Users playing that game. Also Each User can have many Games playing. On other hand you can have Stats which is related to each player and game and only to one user. If it is true let me know that I post a complete answer now.

Comment: @PeymanSeraj Yes but I use Gamelog because my Game model is going to be for the actual game result not the individual player stats. So Players will have many Gamelogs, and only one Stats. Gamelogs will update the Stats table after a Gamelog is registered.

Answer (score 2):

Okay let us assume you have 3 models: `User`, `Stat` and `GameLog`. I suggest you to use singular name for your models to avoid any confusion.

let us start with creating them:

```
php artisan make:model --migration Stat
```

to create both Stat model and stats table.

```
php artisan make:model --migration GameLog
```

to create both GameLog model and game_logs table.

This is the easiest way to create models and tables and bind them together and avoid typos. User model and corresponding table is present with fresh laravel installation.

in you `User` model:

```
public function gameLogs(){
    return $this->hasMany(GameLog::class);
}

public function stats(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Stat::class, GameLog::class);
}
```

in `GameLog` model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class); // each gamelog belongs to just one user
}

public function stat(){
    return $this->hasOne(Stat::class);
}
```

then in your `Stat` model:

```
public function gameLog(){
    return $this->belongsTo(GameLog::class);
}
```

Please remember to construct you database also. If you faced problem in it please let me know and I will help you with.

Now if you want to query a User `gamelogs` you simply need to:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$gamelogs = $user->gameLogs;
```

since `$user` has many `gamelogs` you need to iterate trough them:

```
foreach(gamelogs as gamelog){
    //do your logic
}
```

also if you want to load `stat relationship` of `gamelog` and use it then please read section `eager-loading` in laravel documents and learn about that.

I hope the explanation is clear and enough. If not please let me know. But I have a suggestion for a better database structure. I think it is better to merge stats table and game_logs table together and omit the model GameLog or Stat. Practically it is exactly the same.